# How to fetch data from database and map into react?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

Data is coming from the database is perfectly fine But I don't know how to map that data or how to call that specific column that comes from the database. [This is the output that console shows me, Data is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFFgJ.png)

Any suggestions, please! It would be better if anyone solves this with code.

Rendering Function

```
  const [products,setProducts] = useState({});

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.post('/UserPortal/CartItems/checkout_details_summary.php' , {
        customer_id: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
    } )
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setProducts(response.data);  
        

    })  
  },[])
```

Return

```
 return (
    
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Order summary
      </Typography>
     
     
      <List disablePadding>
   
          <ListItem className={classes.listItem}  key={products.name} >
           <ListItemText secondary={'x'  + products.quantity   }>
                <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                  {products.name}  
               </Typography> 
             </ListItemText>  
              <Typography variant="h5"> {products.total} </Typography>
           </ListItem>
         
       
        <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <ListItemText> <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>Total</Typography></ListItemText>
          <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.total}>
            {'Rs. '  + products.net_total  }
          </Typography>
        </ListItem>
   
      </List>
</React.Fragment>
);
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    
    $customer_id = $request->customer_id;

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM `checkout_details` WHERE `customer_id` = '{$customer_id}' LIMIT 1");

    
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $json = json_encode($row);

}
```

Comment: I would really suggest you take this step by step, and try looking at your network tab, adding some debug output etc. There's many small mistakes here.

Comment: I tried a lot but I don't know how I will get the data. I already took some debugs and outputs. But It says products.map is not a function. I also declare const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);

Comment: The PHP side is also wrong though.

Comment: Can you correct it? please

Answer (score 0):

I think your `const [products,setProducts] = useState({});` should be an array of objects `const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);`.

Then you can iterate over it with `.map` method. You can access the key of each Object destructuring params like this for example:

```
return (
    
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Order summary
      </Typography>
     
     {products.map(({ name, total, net_total }) => 
      <List disablePadding>
   
          <ListItem className={classes.listItem}  key={products.name} >
           <ListItemText secondary={'x'  + products.quantity   }>
                <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                  {name}  
               </Typography> 
             </ListItemText>  
              <Typography variant="h5"> {total} </Typography>
           </ListItem>
         
       
        <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          <ListItemText> <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>Total</Typography></ListItemText>
          <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.total}>
            {'Rs. '  + net_total  }
          </Typography>
        </ListItem>
   
      </List>
    )}
</React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: an error occurred, It says products.map is not a function

Comment: It seems your `products` is not an array. My suggest is to check your server side code and be sure to create a list of objects for each product and store it in your variable state as an array.